# To Resolve - HRESULT : 800706BE exception

Tags: excel, error-handling, runtime-error, hresult, vba

Error: Remote Procedural call failed.
(Exception from HRESULT:0x800706BE)

Occurs when my task/programming opens Excel file often during the process.
The accessed Excel file type is macro enabled and is loaded with conditions of macro over the workbook.

Purpose: in my task when I open excel file multiple times, at a point it shows this error and my process fails.

Solution am looking for : want to avoid this from happening and how to resolve this behaviour any advice/suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand the question, but HRESULT 800706BE -- means `The remote procedure call failed`. Here is the [description](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197814).

Comment: Yes , exactly ! I keep getting this message every time my excel files are opened via the programmed process. @Grigoriy

Comment: Did you ever receive an answer?

Comment: @DavidScott My excel was in edit mode, which was causing the error. As my operation was between two excel sheets. Sorry, for the delay in reply.Thanks all.